# How to load a random file from a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, github-pages

I am trying to create a *question bank* on *GitHub Pages*.
I load a specific file using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var theQuestion = "./questionsBank/"+"question-4"+".html"; //path to load
    $("#question").load(theQuestion);  //loading the question
  
  });
```

Now, there are many files in the *questionsBank* directory and I would like to have a script picking and loading a random one, but I don't know how to do in JS.

- How do you retrieve all filenames in *questionsBank* directory?

I would like to do something like below but don't know how to read filenames in a directory into an array:

```
var questionFolder = './some directory';
var questionFiles = [];
questionFiles = readingFilesandPopulatingIntoArray(questionFolder); \\how to do this?
var folderSize = questionFiles.length ;
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * folderSize);
randomQuestion = questionFiles[randomNumber]; 
$("#question").load(randomQuestion);
```

Comment: as part of build process or pre-commit hook generate an index.js in ./questionsBank/ which is json of all the filenames in the folder (or manually make it), then use ajax to grab it, then do your random index to pick out an item. gh pages is static, anything like this would need to be done before pushing

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, There is no way to read filenames from a folder in a browser environment? Something very easily done in any desktop script.

Comment: your right, no there is no way to read the contents of a directory on the server from the browser unless you expose a list of sorts

Comment: You are making a web app, your files should be in a server and be requested by your code via ajax, in the contrary, if you are building a desktop app, you can use fs module in node.js to open files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [@Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone), the only way of getting the contents of a remote directory is by having an index of it.

Of course Apache has it's own directory scanner, which if configured ok, can render an HTML page with its contents. Then you could fetch that index and loop over the file links in it.

But GitHub Pages does not generates such indexes, so you need to generate it by your own. To do so, you need to do it during the build/deploy process of your page (which we don't know). There, you can add a NodeJS script (or whatever other language you prefer to use, like a plain `bash` script) using, for example, [node's fs dir.read()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dir_read) to get the files list in `./questionsBank/` directory and generating a file to save it somehow (for example, a JSON file containing an Array).

Finally, you can include it directly in your code during the build process by `import`ing it somewhere, or fetching it as you'd fetch any other URL containing a JSON (or whatever other format you decided to use).

Comment: thanks, only been writing desktop java/python codes and didn't expect such difficulty in doing web stuff.

Comment: It's not that dificult: `const response = await fetch(\`${host}/questionsBank/index.json\`); const index = await response.json(); const randomResponse = await fetch( index[ Math.floor(Math.random() * index.length) ] ); const randomContent = randomResponse.text();`